# Android studio grade build failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to import a project in android studio but the gradle build is failing. I've been struggling for hours but can't get it to work. What should I do?

This is what the gradle console says:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':azurMobile:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or > --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

Here's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.viatom.azur"
    android:versionCode="16"
    android:versionName="02.04.02" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.ECGMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.OtherInfo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.ECGDetail"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.ECGAnalyze"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection"
        android:screenOrientation="behind">
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.DailyCheck"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.SPO2Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.TempMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.SLMMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.SLMDetail"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.PedMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.AboutCheckme"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.AboutApp"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.Monitor"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viatom.azur.activity.SpotCheck"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection">
    </activity>
    
    <service android:name="com.viatom.azur.bluetooth.BTUtils">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- 为该Service组件的intent-filter配置action -->
            <action android:name="com.viatom.azur.BTUtils" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </service>
    
    <!-- 友盟统计 -->
    <meta-data android:value="549a0bc4fd98c5dfb5000242" android:name="UMENG_APPKEY"></meta-data>
    <meta-data android:value="Google Play" android:name="UMENG_CHANNEL"/>
</application>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.viatom.azur"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 21

        ndk {
            moduleName "adpcm_docode"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':mPChartLib')
    compile project(':swipeMenuListView')
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile files('libs/umeng-analytics-v5.2.4.jar')
}
```

EDIT:

Logcat:

```
1:21:11 PM Executing tasks: [clean, :azurMobile:generateDebugSources, :azurMobile:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :azurMobile:compileDebugSources, :azurMobile:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :library:generateDebugSources, :library:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :library:compileDebugSources, :library:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :mPChartLib:generateDebugSources, :mPChartLib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :mPChartLib:compileDebugSources, :mPChartLib:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :swipeMenuListView:generateDebugSources, :swipeMenuListView:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :swipeMenuListView:compileDebugSources, :swipeMenuListView:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
1:21:19 PM Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 8s 310ms
```

Comment: delete BOTH `AppName\app\build` and `AppName\build` then rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file delete the commented other language codes

```
 <!-- 为该Service组件的intent-filter配置action --> and  <!-- 友盟统计 -->
```

and then build

Comment: post your logcat output

Comment: you have posted event logs. post logcat output from android monitor

Comment: Or the `Gradle Console` output.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with manifest merger...
Whenever you are trying to compile your project all of the other manifest are being put together for each module. You can find more informations from [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) and [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html)

In other words, if you have more than one build types, their manifest will be merged. So you need to show us your project structre and all of the other manifest.

So we can understand whats wrong when its being merged.

On the other hand you can add versionName and versionCode to gradle

```
  defaultConfig {
    versionCode 16
    versionName "02.04.02"
}
```

Also you may need to delete them from manifest.